# The use of the word progeny

Tags: word-usage

The word [progeny](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/progeny) is defined as

> A descendant or the descendants of a person, animal, or plant;
>   offspring

by Oxford Dictionary.

My question is that if I can use it instead of  "children" to sound formal as in the following contexts.

1. Second hand smoking has  pernicious effects on progenies if their parents smoke in the home.
2. Two out of three progenies in Africa are left out of secondary school.

or the word can only suitable for using in a context in which there is reference to the relationship between parents and children.

Comment: Your uses would not be idiomatic in the US.  John Feltz lays it out pretty well.

Comment: Your second example can be dismissed out-of-hand. Progeny is not used to mean young people irrespective of parentage. It is only used when the genetic lineage needs to be pointed to. And it is a collective term. It refers to all of the descendants of the named antecedent.

Answer (score 9):

Progeny is generally used as an uncountable noun.

"My progeny" could refer to 1 child, or to 8 children, 29 grandchildren, and 95 great-grandchildren.

In your two examples, you are trying to use progeny as a countable noun.  It's incorrect to do so.  "Children" is formal enough to use in your two examples.

Comment: I'm also pretty certain that "progeny" needs to be associated with something either with an "of" or with a possessive reference to it.  "Tom's progeny",  "the progeny of WW2 vets, etc"..  While I wouldn't want to be the last word on that, I would certainly advise caution.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the first answer, *progeny* is a non-countable noun meaning descendants, so in your example, the plural form *progenies* is inapt. The Ngram viewer find that the plural is used as a term of art in plant breeding to indicate separate populations of descendants.  For example from 
a [USDA Forest Service research note](https://books.google.com/books?id=sZfWXKAGYG0C&pg=PP6&dq=%22progenies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA-MHVp7zRAhWENiYKHYtJD2Q4MhDoAQg4MAY#v=onepage&q=%22progenies%22&f=false):

> The yearly height increment of the wind-pollination **progenies** was consistently 8 to 12 percent less than that of the cross-pollination **progenies**....

The progenies here are three groups of trees, each group the descendants of different stands of trees in the Cascades, a mountain range in the western US.